# How to tell my Macbook to never use the speaker but only headphone

Tags: mac, audio, macbook-pro, mute

The macbook is used in the office. So I do not want to make it sound in the speaker. It should output sound when there is an earphone connected to it. Otherwise no sound.

Is it possible to configure in such a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Mac remembers loudness settings for each device individually. This means you can do the following:

- Turn down the volume when you are on loudspeakers to 0 (or mute).
- Plug in your headphones.
- Turn up the volume.
- Plug out the headphones. Your volume will be changed to the loudspeaker levels again (i.e., muted).

These settings should actually be remembered, even when rebooting your Mac.

Comment: I've caught mine with speakers on occasionally in the office even though they have never been used. Works great 98% of the time though!

Comment: This even makes the boot sound of the mac go away. The volume settings for your internal speakers are stored in the nvram, so you won't hear the bootup sound, if you don't like it.